# How to find the first element if Xpath returns a list of elements(selenium-python)

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(path)
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get("https://www.flipkart.com")
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="_2AkmmA _29YdH8"]').click()
browser.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys("Mobiles")
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='vh79eN']").click()
p = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='_3wU53n']")
```

Using the above code, I have to search for **Mobiles** in flipkart and click on any Mobile which should that open page onto new Tab.

I am facing issue with locating a mobile as Xpath returns a list of Mobiles. I want to find the first element and click so that it opens in new tab.

Can Anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: p[0].click() Plus some options.

Comment: To click on first element Use p[0].click()

Comment: Just in case you need your xpath should return only first element then do `(//div[@class='_3wU53n'])[1]`

Answer (score 0):

When you used `browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='_3wU53n']")` p will be a lists, so you can access items as easy as p[0], more info [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp).

But if you only need the first element, I suggest u should use `browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='_3wU53n']")` without the "s" as it should select the first element in that class

Answer (score 0):

You can store in List by using list class in selenium.

List  lists=driver.findElements(By.xpath(".."));
lists.get(0).click();

//Above code for click first element in lists

Answer (score 0):

Once you "CLICK" the SEARCH button, the webpage redirects to a new page which shows the list of mobile. However, it takes some time to load the page. So you need to add some delay to it, so as to perform the next actions.

```
<the code above remains the same>
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='vh79eN']").click()
import time
time.sleep(3) # Added a delay
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='_3wU53n']").click() # Changed the "elements" to "element"
```

This opens the first mobile phone in the new tab.

PS. This code works great if you need only the first mobile. If you need all the mobiles on the page, you will have to create a loop for it!